# qt create button when right click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I am new in qt I want to create a button when I right click

There is my code:

```
void MainWindow::right_clicked(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
           QPushButton *item = new QPushButton();
           item->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/7928748-removebg-preview(1).ico"));
           item->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
           item->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(event->x(), event->y()), QSize(32, 32)));
        }
}
```

But nothing appears

Comment: Thank you but doesn't work

Comment: Is  `right_clicked` a slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture any mouse event in a `QWidget` you must override the `mousePressEvent` method.

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
```

And in the mainwindow.cpp, implement it as follows:

```cpp
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
        // make mainwindow parent of this button by passing "this" pointer
        QPushButton *item = new QPushButton(QIcon(":/images/close-button-icon"), "", this);

        // set button position to the location of mouse click
        item->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(event->x()-16, event->y()-16), QSize(32, 32)));
        item->show();
    }
}
```

If you don't save the pointer to QPushButton, then you will not be able to use it afterwards.

[image: Demo]